# Slack reply to response_url with ephemeral message not working

Tags: node.js, slack-api

I'm working on an interactive Slack app written in Node.js with Express. When the user clicks a button on an interactive message, I want to post an ephemeral message; however, the replies always appear publicly in the channel. Furthermore, whether or not I set the `response_type`, the original message with the interactive elements that the user clicked on disappears. My code looks like this:

```
const request = require('request');

app.post('/slack-interactivity', async function(req, res) {
  const payload = JSON.parse(req.body.payload);
  sendResponse(payload.response_url, 'you clicked');
  res.send('received');
});


function sendResponse(responseUrl, response) {
  request.post({url: responseUrl,
                method: 'POST',
                json: {
                  response_type: "ephemeral",
                  text: response}});
}
```

When I click on a button in an interactive slack message, I see "you clicked" written publicly to the channel, but I want it to be ephemeral.

Any ideas why this could be happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't possible (as of 5/17/2019)

A message will retain its visibility for life. Meaning you can't go from in_channel to ephemeral (or vice versa).

You can include: `replace_original: false` and the ephemeral message will display.

Behind the scenes replace_original is acting like an update, not delete and create new message.

Your code defaults to replace_original: true which preforms an **update** and thus is not going to work.

Comment: Ah, `replace_original` was it. I'm finding there are a lot of undocumented settings in the Slack APIs that don't do what I'd expect. Who'd have thought responding to the **response**URL would replace the original rather than _responding_ to it? Congrats on the 125 rep :)

Comment: Ah, right I can't award the bounty until 24 hours have passed.